# Trying to subtract all values in a hash from a variable

Tags: ruby

I have recently started to learn how to program on ruby. Currently, I am stuck on a hash where I am trying to subtract each hash value from a total amount. So far it only subtracts from the last value of the hash.

```
categories_hash = {
    "Bills" => 100,
    "Utilities" => 150,
    "Groceries" => 200
}

balance = 500

categories_hash.each do |k, v|
    $new_balance = balance - v
end
puts $new_balance
```

The result I am expecting is supposed to be 50 but I am getting 300. It seems to only subtract the last value from the balance.

I've also tried:

```
$new_balance = balance - categories_hash.values
```

However, that then gives me an error stating "Array can't be coerced into Integer".

What is the best way for me to solve this problem?

Comment: Try and stay far, far away from global variables like `$new_balance`. Instead just use regular variables, no `$` prefix. The reason these are trouble is because they're global across your entire program and can easily be mis-used by other parts of your code, if not inadvertently stomped and reassigned.

Comment: The quick fix here is `balance -= v` in the `each` loop.

Comment: @Maxx : Since you never modify `balance`, and always calculate `$new_balance` from fresh in the loop, the final value of `$new_balance` will just be `balance - categories_hash["Groceries"]`. This not a particular problem of Ruby (except for the fact that Ruby guarantees the order in which Hash elements are processed), but a basic problem of your algorithm. You would run into the same problem if you would code it in a different language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to extract the values from the hash before summing them:

```
balance - categories_hash.sum(&:last)  #=> 50
```

Alternatively,

```
-categories_hash.sum(-balance, &:last) #=> 50
```

See [Array#sum](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sum).

Comment: Hi Cary, thank you for your reply and help, I very much appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_balance = balance - categories_hash.values.sum
```

Since values is an array you need to sum it before substract from `balance`

Comment: Hi Agung, thank you so much for your reply and I just tried it and it worked perfectly. Thank you :)

Comment: @Maxx no worries.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `inject` method for requirement just like below

```
categories_hash = {
    "Bills" => 100,
    "Utilities" => 150,
    "Groceries" => 200
}

# working inject with values(Array) 

balance = 500

categories_hash.values.inject(balance, :-)
#=> 50

# working inject with directly (Hash)

balance = 500
categories_hash.inject(balance){|b, val| b-= val.last}
#=> 50
```

Comment: Or `categories_hash.inject(balance) { |b, (_, v)| b - v }` which uses [array decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) for the key-value pair. You also don't need `-=`, just `-`

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with your first example, just update the `balance` inside the loop:

```
balance = 500
old_balance = balance # backup just in case
categories_hash.each do |_, v|
    balance -= v
end

balance #=> 50
old_balance #=> 500
```

Where `balance -= v` is the same as `balance = balance - v`

For the shorter version of the code refer to other answers in this thread.

Comment: Hi iGian, thank you for your help. Much appreciated :)